# Get multiple substrings from cell by separator

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple values in one cell that are ordered like this:

```
0#0#54232#5#123# ...
```

Now I want to put every single value in a separate cell. I tried working with SEARCH, FIND, LEFT, MID functions and so on, but everthing looks so fiddly and I can't get it to work. My idea was to look for every # in the text and get every substring in between. But with 20+ values in a single cell this gets very confusing by the end.

EDIT: The lengths of the values can vary

Comment: Is text-to-columns an option? If not how about VBA?

Comment: No thats not an option, because the values in the cell are generated by calling VBA. text-to-column tries to split the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put your string in cell B3, and in cell C2, I've put following formula:

```
=LEFT(B3;FIND.SPEC("#";B3)-1)
```

In cell C3, I've put following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B3;C2&"#";"";1)
```

I've been dragging the whole thing to the right, and row 2 gave me the results you are looking for. (You might need to add some `IfBlank()` or `IfError()` but you understand what I mean)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FILTERXML` to split the string (this solution will work on Office 365, since dynamic arrays need to be available):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;"#";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[string-length()>0]")
```

[image: Split string using FILTERXML in Excel]

There has recently been a nice question here on Stackoverflow that I highly recommend to read:

[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/12418842)

Comment: Nice. If there can be empty nodes, you can exclude them through `//s[node()]` also. If the string wont end by `#` it's simply `//s`. Maybe also worth noting that without Excel O365 one should use `INDEX` to pull values from the resulting array. +

Answer (score 2):

You can use following formula (also in older excel versions):

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1;"#";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s["&ROW()&"]");"")
```

[image]